# Kustomize - how to apply values on variables used in the base overlay ConfigMap?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kustomize

I have the following file structure:

```
.
├── base/
│   ├── some_image_1/
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   │   └── config-map-image-1.yaml
│   ├── some_image_2/
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── some_image_3/
│   ├── ...
│   ├── global-config-map.yaml
│   └── kustomization.yaml
└── overlays/
    ├── dev/
    │   ├── kustomization.yaml
    │   └── dev-configmap.yaml
    └── prod/
        └── ...
```

`config-map-image-1.yaml` contains variables used in it's deployments which will be overridden by the `global-config-map.yaml`.
The values there also have variables, that will be overridden in each overlay.
So something like this:

```
# config-map-image-1.yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: image-1-configmap
data:
  CUSTOM_CSS_BUCKET: $(BUCKET_CONF)


# global-config-map.yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: global-configmap
data:
  BUCKET_CONF: "config-bucket-$(ENV)-environment"


# dev-configmap.yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dev-configmap
data:
  ENV: "dev"
```

The `kustomization.yaml` for each image is pretty basic, along the lines of:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- ...

configurations:
- ...

patchesStrategicMerge:
- config-map-image-1.yaml
```

(Or without `patchesStrategicMerge` and config map in `resources`).

The root `kustomization.yaml` of the base is more complicated, because it uses `vars` (and `replacements`, `configurations`, `patches` too). The values from the `global-config-map.yaml` are used in the `vars` section too:

```
# base's root kustomize.yaml
...
resources:
- global-config-map.yaml
- ...

...

vars:
- fieldref:
    fieldPath: data.BUCKET_CONF
  name: BUCKET_CONF
  objref:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    name: global-configmap
...
```

The `kustomization.yaml` of the `dev` overlay is:

```
---
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: gnp-beeplugin-dev
resources:
- dev-configmap.yaml
- ../../base

configurations:
- configs.yaml

vars:
- name: ENV
  objref:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    name: dev-configmap
  fieldref:
    fieldPath: data.ENV
```

`configs.yaml` contains:

```
varReference:
- path: data
  kind: ConfigMap
```

How should I properly define the `kustomization.yaml` for each overlay? How should I modify the `kustomization.yaml` of the base overlay?

Currently, when I run `kustomize build` on the base overlay I receive, in short:

```
# result from base
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: image-1-configmap
data:
  CUSTOM_CSS_BUCKET: config-bucket-$(ENV)-environment
....

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: global-configmap
data:
  BUCKET_CONF: config-bucket-$(ENV)-environment
```

Which is fine and expected, but when I run `kustomize build` from the `dev` overlay, the only place the values change correctly are in `global-configmap` and no where else. I would expect the `CUSTOM_CSS_BUCKET` value to contain `dev` and not `$(ENV)`.

What am I missing? How can I apply the `dev-configmap` before `global-configmap` is applied on all the images?

Kustomize version: v5.3.0